# wpf apply staticresouce based upon data

Tags: wpf, binding, styles

How can I apply a static resource by name based upon data?  I know that I can write a data trigger for styling properties, but I want to apply an entire style based upon bound data.

Ex:
if (condition) CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource OptionalFieldCellPresenter}"
else CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource RequiredFieldCellPresenter}"

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom converter to take care of this.  The Converter class would look like this:

```
//''' <summary>
//''' Returns a Style  based upon the text that is passed into the Convert
//''' function in the 'value' object.
//''' </summary>
//''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class NameToStyleConverter
   Implements IValueConverter

   Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
      Dim styleName As String = CStr(value)
      Dim styl As System.Windows.Style

      styl = Application.Current.TryFindResource(styleName)

      Return styl

   End Function

   Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
      Throw New NotImplementedException("This method or operation is not implemented.")
   End Function
End Class
```

In the XAML for your window, you would have the following:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NameToStyleConverter x:Key="NameToStyleConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

where 'local' is the defined namespace for your application.

Implementation might look like this:

```
Style="{Binding Path=MyStyleNameText, Converter={StaticResource NameToStyleConverter}"
```

Or optionally, you can always refer to the Converter from code.  You pass in a string and it returns a style.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a style to the parent control, it looks like you are using a DataGrid, with a default CellStyleTemplate.

Then in Style.Triggers add a data trigger to swap the style to another style when a condition is met

Comment: i like the idea, but i think my example might be misleading.  if i write a data trigger in the style, then replacing the style will remove the data trigger - right?

Comment: not if you give the style a key and use the BasedOn attribute in the new style